# React table updating with websocket

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

I have connection to WebSocket that sends me a message every 0.1s, than i write it to useState. Then react rerender whole table with new element. Is there any method to add new element to table or a part of a table, avoiding rerendering of all other elements?

I tried to use MillionJS library to optimise table rendering, but it's not enough. It continue rerendering the whole table

```
const UplinksTableBody = () => {
const { Uplinks, lastMessage } = useContext(UplinksContext)
const Keys = useMemo(() => (Object.keys(Schema.Cells)), [])

const { has, get } = useSearchParams()

return (
<TableBody
  className={'hover:bg-inherit'}

>
  <For each={Uplinks}>
    {
      (uplink: {
        [property in ISchema['Cells'][keyof ISchema]['dataField']]: string
      }) => (
        <UplinkTableRow
          
          uplink={uplink}
          Keys={Keys}
          active={
            has(uniqueField)
            && uplink[uniqueField] === get(uniqueField)
          }
        />
      )
    }
  </For>
</TableBody>
  )
  }

 export default UplinksTableBody
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.